# How can I get the distance between a point and a line segment following the direction given by a vector?

Tags: javascript, typescript, linear-algebra

I am trying to code a function in typescript to get the distance from a point to a line segment in the direction specified by a vector in a 2D space. The point has coordinates x,z, the line segment is described by two points and the vector is a normalised vector with coordinates x,z. If there is no distance between the point and the segment (the line in the direction defined by the vector doesn't intersect the segment) it should return undefined, else, it should return the distance.
I found many examples on internet about how to get the minimum distance between a point and a line segment but none about getting the distance in a given direction. Attached is an image that describes better what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Is it a line segment or a line? What if the vector doesn't intersect with the line segment?

Comment: without any clue where x is, or anything about that line, it's the green bit labelled d ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - perhaps if you added the code/structure/whatever that defines the `line`, `x` and the `vector` you may get quicker help

Comment: yeah, only thing we can say now is, take a ruler and measuer ;)

Comment: here is how to find interesection of lines (the intersection point) https://www.wikihow.com/Algebraically-Find-the-Intersection-of-Two-Lines

Comment: given points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) (cartesian coordinates) the distance between them is sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)

Comment: You can create an equation of a line using a point and a vector and then you can calculate the intersection point of two lines

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Right now you're either asking for a verbal description of the implementation, or you want someone to write it for you from scratch.  Either way is problematic (a verbal description is open to interpretation, and writing code from scratch isn't really a good fit for SO, since it's a lot of extra work for answerers with a high likelihood of the questioner saying "that's not what I meant"). If you can provide an actual example, others can paste it into their own IDEs, see the issue, and get to work implementing/fixing stuff.

Comment: So, just for fun, I wrote up [a possible approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAgyPw).  But I have no idea if this is what you meant, and without a framework and test cases from you it's hard for me or you to know if I've succeeded.  So, could you [edit] to provide those and if my approach works for it then I'll write up an answer explaining how it works?  And if it doesn't then you can tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: To sum up. Step 1: find the intersection point. Step 2: calculate distance between two points.